# Bower dependencies folder won't expand after VS crash

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

After referencing angular version "1.4.0-beta.5" on VS2015 CTP 5, VS threw an exception and closed.

When opened again, the project where I've tried to reference angular 1.4 won't expand it's bower reference folder (Refereces/Bower) anymore.

I've already removed angular, replaced with angular 1.3, but nothing changed. There is nothing wrong with bower.json. I've replaced it too.

Any help making the folder expand again without porting everything to a new app?

#### Edit: 02/March/2015

Reproduced twice on other machines. Environment: VS2015 CTP-5 on a Windows 8.1 Pro pt-BR. It's an AspNet5 web project.

Whenever you add a reference to angular 1.4.0 beta-5 (and probably other beta packages) on Bower, VS crashes and Bower references folder stop working.

Here follows the angular reference (for bower.json) which causes this error:

```
"angular": "1.4.0-beta.5"
```

After saving bower.json, if you right-click on Bower folder and choose "Restore Packages" vs will start restoring until it reaches the beta package than an exception is thrown and Bower references folder won't expand anymore.

I'll just use angular 1.3.x for now.

At least here, nothing really helped. Renaming the app, changing contents from bower.json, deleting bower.json and creating a new one, nothing.

You can rename your project and copy it's content directly to a new one. It will work. Just don't forget to change angular reference or it will break the new project too =)

Comment: I've forwarded this question to the team that works on this feature. Awaiting a response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add any string to the "name" attribute and try again?

"name": "something",

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Done that. Nothing has changed, though :(

Removed "name", changed to "name":"the.book.is.on.the.table", reverted back to project name. All with full solution save + VS restart. Bower seems to be working but I can't see the references folder.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Bower works fine but in VS Dependencies it says, "Bower (Syntax error in bower.json)". There probably was an error at some point. Then the error was cleared. But VS is not re validating. That's my guess. I am on the RC version of 2015.

Comment: Same here also on VS2015 RC, seems like a VS issue to me

Comment: @ScottAdams Did you find a solution to this? Apparently, in VS 2015 (without the RC) this still happens. And I have no idea why.

Comment: @AlexEndris, sorry for the delay, I no longer have the problem with update 1.